# Interpreting !12 as string and not as terminal history

Tags: command-line, bash

Using the sample command below in curl, it doesn't work as expected:

```
curl -ik "http://localhost/index.php?username=parto&password=hello!23"
```

I expect the parameters to be passed to include:

```
username = parto
password = hello!23
```

But the part `!23` in the password is interpreted as a [history event designator](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/history.3.html). If the 23rd command is `sudo apt-get update`, the commands becomes:

```
curl -ik "http://localhost/index.php?username=parto&password=hellosudo apt-get update"
```

> Event Designators
>          An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the
>          history list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative
>          to the current position in the history list.

```
   >!      Start a history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
          newline, = or (.
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
   !string
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current
          position in the history list starting with string.
   !?string[?]
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current
          position in the history list containing string.  The trailing
          ? may be omitted if string is followed immediately by a
          newline.
   ^string1^string2^
          Quick substitution.  Repeat the last command, replacing
          string1 with string2.  Equivalent to ``!!:s/string1/string2/''
          (see Modifiers below).
   !#     The entire command line typed so far.
```

Without using extra characters as depicted in the man page (quoted above), how can we 'tell' the terminal NOT to interpret the command above (!23) as an event designator?

Comment: Note that history expansion is only enabled by default in *interactive* shells: if you put the curl commands in a script, it should work. You can disable history expansion in the terminal (interactive shell) using `set +o histexpand` or `set +H`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way how to use the exclamation mark in double quotes. Backslash it unquoted,  or use single quotes instead of double quotes, as special characters aren't expanded in single quotes.

```
curl -ik "http://localhost/index.php?username=parto&password=hello"\!"23"
curl -ik 'http://localhost/index.php?username=parto&password=hello!23'
```

Comment: The single quotes worked. I didn't try out the first one though